# Editing property bag values using powershell

Tags: 2010, powershell, property-bag

What is property bag in SharePoint 2010?

How do I retrieve values from a property bag and get/set the values using powershell?

Comment: Here is the post explaining to get and set property bag values in SharePoint 2013 apps using CSOM 

http://sureshpydi.blogspot.in/2013/05/set-and-get-property-bag-values-in.html

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
#------------------------Code-------------------------------- 
$url= Read-Host 'Enter the site Name'
$site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($url)
$rootWeb = $site.RootWeb

Write-Host -foregroundcolor Green "The current Site"$rootWeb 

$value= Read-Host 'Enter the property name'
$Adminurl = "propertyName"

$rootWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = $true;
$Currentvalue = $rootWeb.Properties[$Adminurl]
Write-Host -foregroundcolor Green "The current value of the property bag is "$Currentvalue

if (!$rootWeb.Properties.ContainsKey($Adminurl))
{ 
         $rootWeb.Properties.Add($Adminurl, $value);
}
else
{
         $rootWeb.Properties[$Adminurl] = $value;
}                        

       $rootWeb.Properties.Update();
       $rootWeb.Update();

       $rootWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = $false;

$UpdatedValue =  $rootWeb.Properties[$Adminurl]
Write-Host -foregroundcolor Green "Value of the property bag is updated with " $UpdatedValue


if ($rootWeb -ne $null)
{
    $rootWeb.Dispose()

}
If ($site -ne $null)
{
    $site.Dispose();
}

Write-Host -foregroundcolor Green "Script has finished executing "
```

### Using c#:

```
SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Site;
{
    using (SPWeb spWebRoot = site.RootWeb)
    {

        // unsafe updates are required to be able to write to the property bag
        string key = "administrationurl";
        string myValue = "nikh";
        spWebRoot.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

        // you must check to see if the collection has a value in the assigned key already

        if (!spWebRoot.AllProperties.ContainsKey(key))

        spWebRoot.Properties.Add(key, myValue);

        else

        spWebRoot.AllProperties[key] = myValue;



        // update the properties
        spWebRoot.Update();

        spWebRoot.Properties.Update();
        spWebRoot.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: When using Powershell : make sure to update the properties & allproperties()

Answer (score 6):

Share-Point property bags provide an easy-to-use storage mechanism for any serializable configuration data.
Below is the sample code:

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb;

//To store data in property bag

web.Properties["TestKey"]="TestData";

//To retrieve data stored in property bag                 
if (web.Properties.ContainsKey("TestKey"))
{
  string strResult=web.Properties["TestKey"];
}
```

We must ensure that any data we store in Property Bags is serializable.
If you attempt to persist non-serializable types in property bags,the configuration database or the content database 
may get corrupted. So, it is recommended you use "[Application Setting Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798488.aspx)" to store\retrieve values in property bags

Comment: "the content database may get corrupted" - really?

Comment: The content database may get corrupted if you try to store non-serializable objects in property bags.

Comment: "Corrupted" is a very strong word you're implying something that simply will not happen. The property bag is just a key/value store and you can put whatever you want in whatever format you want. If your object is not serializable then you would have to provide a custom serialization scheme anyway.

Comment: I think we should not put whatever we want in Property bags. 
I will recommend to stick to the guidelines from msdn here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649798.aspx. 

I agree that content DB will not corrupt so easily by a developer mistake.
However, it may not be true for all kind of mistakes. 
So again it is better to follow "Patterns & Practices' recommended at msdn here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff770300.aspx. 
As per the guidance "developers risk corrupting the configuration database or the content database if they attempt to persist non-serializable types.."

Comment: Very interesting about the non-serializable objects.

Comment: +1 @Amit. I stand corrected, though I don't know what manner of WTF is going on for Microsoft to flag this to be a possible issue!

Answer (score 3):

Property bag is basically properties attached on web site ,site collection , web application and farm level.

You can check out the codeplex tool here for more understanding - http://pbs2010.codeplex.com/

You also have a list of cmdlets from Powershell for property bag - http://collab.rdacorp.com/2010/05/sharepoint-2010-property-bag-cmdlet.html

Answer (score 2):

To interact with the PropertyBags in code you simply refer to the object's Propeties member.

There are PropertyBags available for the SPFarm, SPWebApplication, SPSite, and SPWeb.

To set a value:   site.Properties["PropertyName"] = "foo";

To read a value:  string myProperty= site.Properties["PropertyName"].ToString();

Answer (score 0):

One of the uses of SharePoint Manager 2010 (http://spm.codeplex.com/) is to view and update the property bags.  This is nice in that it doesn't require a feature deployed to the environment so I use either this or the pbs2010 feature that @Deepu Nair recommended.

Comment: I think it is only useful if you know at design-time what you want to store in property bags. This is not the case most of the time when you implement complex business logic

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question.  I will post a different answer.