# SharePoint Property Bags

Tags: properties

Has any one worked with SharePoint Property Bags ? I found few helpful articles but that helped me only partially. I want to write a code that writes and retrieves information from Property Bag. I have the code with me but confused where to write it and what type of item should I select.

Thanks.

Comment: REFER : http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/21324/editing-property-bag-values-using-powershell

Answer (score 7):

A good way to visualize this and to learn more about the structure of the property bags is to use SharePoint Manager and just browse the DOM. http://spm.codeplex.com/

For example to access the property bag of the root folder in a list you can use this code:

```
string someProperty = "Some data to store";
MyList.RootFolder.Properties["YourProperty"] = someProperty;
```

Then to read the property use something like this:

```
string someProperty = MyList.RootFolder.Properties["YourProperty"] as string;
```

Comment: I'm afraid you've forgotten to update the SPFolder object in your sample code, in order to save changes to database

Answer (score 2):

There is a codeplex project which could give you an overview of how property bags can be used in SharePoint 2010 or 2007. Check this out - http://pbs2010.codeplex.com/

Comment: After searching and working with Property Bags, things got cleared. You can update Property Bags using any SharePoint Object Model Code - Event Receiver, Visual Web Part, etc...

Answer (score 0):

```
#------------------------Code-------------------------------- 
$url= Read-Host 'Enter the site Name'
$site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($url)
$rootWeb = $site.RootWeb

Write-Host -foregroundcolor Green "The current Site"$rootWeb 

$value= Read-Host 'Enter the property name'
$Adminurl = "propertyName"

$rootWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = $true;
$Currentvalue = $rootWeb.Properties[$Adminurl]
Write-Host -foregroundcolor Green "The current value of the property bag is "$Currentvalue

if (!$rootWeb.Properties.ContainsKey($Adminurl))
{ 
         $rootWeb.Properties.Add($Adminurl, $value);
}
else
{
         $rootWeb.Properties[$Adminurl] = $value;
}                        

       $rootWeb.Properties.Update();
       $rootWeb.Update();

       $rootWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = $false;

$UpdatedValue =  $rootWeb.Properties[$Adminurl]
Write-Host -foregroundcolor Green "Value of the property bag is updated with " $UpdatedValue


if ($rootWeb -ne $null)
{
    $rootWeb.Dispose()

}
If ($site -ne $null)
{
    $site.Dispose();
}

Write-Host -foregroundcolor Green "Script has finished executing "
```

### Using c#:

```
SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Site;
{
    using (SPWeb spWebRoot = site.RootWeb)
    {

        // unsafe updates are required to be able to write to the property bag
        string key = "administrationurl";
        string myValue = "nikh";
        spWebRoot.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

        // you must check to see if the collection has a value in the assigned key already

        if (!spWebRoot.AllProperties.ContainsKey(key))

        spWebRoot.Properties.Add(key, myValue);

        else

        spWebRoot.AllProperties[key] = myValue;



        // update the properties
        spWebRoot.Update();

        spWebRoot.Properties.Update();
        spWebRoot.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
    }
}
```