# Property Bag in SharePoint

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise

I am using property bag to store config value using below code.

```
SPFarm farmObject = SPFarm.Local;
farmObject .Properties.Add("PropertyKey", "PropertyValue");
farmObject .Update();
```

This code is working fine. But Now if i want to update and remove property than it is not working.

```
SPFarm farmObject = SPFarm.Local;
 if (farmObject.Properties != null && farmObject.Properties.Count > 0)
 {
 if (farmObject.Properties.ContainsKey("PropertyKey"))
 {
  farmObject.Properties["PropertyKey"] = "New Property Value";
         farmObject.Update();
 }
 }
```

Same case for remove also.
In farmObject.Update line nothing happens. No error, no message and nothing is working.I have debug but after this update line nothing is happen and debug is not work further.
Once after adding farmObject.Update() is not working for update and also for remove also.

I have custom application page in central admin. And on click of button click I have write this code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Editing property bag values using powershell](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/21324/editing-property-bag-values-using-powershell)

Answer (score 2):

Really, it seems to me like your code sample should work.

Check out [storing custom objects in sharepoint farm property bags](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/bd710974-2b4b-45db-961b-c174fc8587f5/storing-custom-objects-in-sharepoint-farm-property-bags):

```
Modify the property value farm level
------------------------------------
SPFarm farmObject = SPFarm.Local;
if (farmObject.Properties != null && farmObject.Properties.Count > 0)
{
    if (farmObject.Properties.ContainsKey("PropertyKey"))
    {
        farmObject.Properties["PropertyKey"] = "New Property Value";
        farmObject.Update();
    }
}
```

It's the exact same code as what you have.

It's also the exact same code found [here](http://hiren-j-patel.blogspot.com/2012/07/save-value-in-sharepoint-property-bags.html) and [here](http://www.fivenumber.com/understanding-sharepoint-property-bag-settings/).

Comment: If calling `Update()` on the Properties object pushes the changes to the database, is there even a need to call `Update()` on the Farm object?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure. You could test it and figure it out. I've found code samples online that don't use the properties update method at all (which seems like they may be wrong?), and some that use both updates.

Comment: Interesting.  After a quick test in Powershell, I got an error because `System.Collections.Hashtable` doesn't contain a method named 'Update'!  So you can't actually do `farmObject.Properties.Update()`.  (I also verified that there is no Update method available on `SPFarm.Local.Properties` in VS.)  I did however, manage to get a new value saved using just `farmObject.Update()`, so I'm not sure where the OP's problem is really coming from.  And maybe those code samples you found that don't use the properties update method are actually right.

Comment: Seems you're right. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.sppersistedobject.properties.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Remove farm key using this code,

```
farmObject.AllProperties.Remove("PropertyKey"); 
farmObject.Properties["PropertyKey"] = null; 
farmObject.Update(); 
farmObject.Properties.Update();
```