# How to include end user editable resources?

Tags: 2010, resource-files

I have a custom list item form that sends email notifications when certain things happen. I want the text of the email to be changeable without having to recompile or redeploy a solution. I thought I could use a resx file deployed to the mapped Resource folder, and tried:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button1.Text = SPUtility.GetLocalizedString("$Resources:String1", "Resource1", (uint)SPContext.Current.Web.Locale.LCID);
        }
```

But apparently editing the resx file after deployment doesn't change anything... because it has been translated into a binary file and that is what is actually being checked?

So, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

2 ways you can get it :

1. Add the text of the email to the web.config 
   OR
2. Store the value in property bag and fetch the value in your code.
   PS : [Editing property bag values using powershell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/21324/editing-property-bag-values-using-powershell)

Comment: Highly recommend the 2nd option for supportability and maintainability.

Comment: It seems like with both those options changes would need to be done by an admin on the server, is that correct?