# Can user define and embed variables to pages?

Tags: variable

User have a hundred of statistic figures. He want to build several report based on these figures. The reports will be built as publishing pages. These reports will contains the statistic figures. Whenever the figures being updated, the "numbers" on the reports will be up-to-date.

My 1st thought would be create some list and insert the lists into the report pages. But I cannot embed only 1 cell or 1 number into the page. I have to embed entire list.

Any advice?

Comment: Have you tried adding a custom property to the page, which can be updated when needed?

Comment: May I know how to do that?

Comment: Look at the answer to [Editing property bag values using powershell](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/21444/6382) which also expalins how to use C# to read and edit properties.

Comment: Finally I have suggested "Reusable Content List" to fulfill this requirement

Comment: Great! Can you add that as an answer, so others with the same problem can get a valid answer? Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I use the OOB feature "Reusable Content List" to fulfill the requirement.

Beside, you can look for alternative at the answer to [Editing property bag values using powershell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/21444/6382) which also expalins how to use C# to read and edit properties

P.S. Notice that "Reusable Content List" is a half completed product. There is no way to track which pages have used which reusable content (unless you program yourself). The worst part is, until you remove all reusable content from all related pages, you cannot delete a reusable content item!