# Change property bag value in SharePoint 2013 using powershell

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, powershell

I tried to amend SharePoint site property bag value using the code in 
[Editing property bag values using powershell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/21324/editing-property-bag-values-using-powershell)

However, I couldn't find the property. It seems that `$rootWeb.Properties[myProperty]` returns blank always whereas in SharePoint designer. I could see `myProperty` with value associated to it. 
`$rootWeb.Properties` contains sharepoint defaults only. Non of user custom values are showing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `AllProperties`.

Adding a new property bag:

```
$web.AllProperties.Add("Key", "Value")
$web.Update()
```

Changing the property:

```
$web.AllProperties["Key"] = "New Value"
$web.Update()
```

Retrieving the property:

```
$value = $web.AllProperties["Key"]
```

Hope this helps! ;)